# Noob Java : Linked list deleting. Header error

Tags: java, linked-list

My job is to make a scheduler via Java.

I have to store course infos with linked list.

---

The problem is, I believe my algorithm can deal with header too.

I have no idea where the problem happened.

Please help noob.

---

Here is what course class has.

```
private String department;
private int number;
private String description;
private int starting_hour;
private boolean requiredForMajor;
private int credits;
private char[] days;

Course next;
```

First course's index is 0.

"next" stores information of next course stored in linked list.

---

### My code

I really want to make it with recursive form.

```
public Course deleteCourse(int index) {

    if (index==0) {
        return this.next;
    }

    else {
        if (this.next!=null){
            this.next=this.next.deleteCourse(index-1);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

It works pretty well on index which is not zero.

Here are few results that this code produced.

---

### RESULT 1 : Working Well

> === testing method deleteCourse() ===
>
> - 1. removing itself
>
> Before: /-A100-/
>
> 1) Deleted A100 : /-(empty)-/
>
> Result: //
>
> - 2. remove everything in order (except header)
>
> Before: /-A100->-A150->-B100->-B200-/
>
> 1) Deleted A150 : /-A100->-B100->-B200-/
>
> 2) Deleted B100 : /-A100->-B200-/
>
> 3) Deleted B200 : /-A100-/
>
> Result: /-A100-/
>
> - 3. remove beyond index bound
>
> (NOTHING has to be deleted in this test)
>
> Before: /-A100->-A150->-B100-/
>
> 1) Deleted [invalid] : /-A100->-A150->-B100-/
>
> 2) Deleted [invalid] : /-A100->-A150->-B100-/
>
> 3) Deleted [invalid] : /-A100->-A150->-B100-/
>
> Result: /-A100->-A150->-B100-/
>
> - 4. remove in random order
>
> Before: /-A100->-A150->-B100->-B200->-B300->-B500-/
>
> 1) Deleted B300 : /-A100->-A150->-B100->-B200->-B500-/
>
> 2) Deleted B100 : /-A100->-A150->-B200->-B500-/
>
> 3) Deleted B200 : /-A100->-A150->-B500-/
>
> Result: /-A100->-A150->-B500-/
>
> -- test PASSed --

---

### RESULT 2 : Error on Header

However, it has problem dealing with header item.

Here is the error messeage.

> - 5. remove multiple item including header
>
> Before: /-A100->-A150->-B100->-B200->-B300-/
>
> 1) Deleted B100 (index=2) : /-A100->-A150->-B200->-B300-/
>
> 2) Deleted A100 (index=0) : /-A100->-A150->-B200->-B300-/
>
> 3) Deleted A150 (index=1) : /-A100->-B200->-B300-/
>
> Result: /
>
> Incorrect list order/item: Current: A100/ Correct: A150
>
> Full list is...: /-A100->-B200->-B300-/
>
> Failed to remove course: Incorrect list order/item

Comment: Why not just use the LinkedList from Java?  There are several versions of LinkedList that should do quite well for you.  In Java 7 LinkedLists have been added.

Comment: @Dale My professor never lets me to do that...

Comment: Please provide also the code for `Course` and the code that generated the test results

Comment: When the header needs to be removed you are simply returning the the next item but not removing it.  Shouldn't you be removing it?

Comment: If there is no reference to it the garbage collector will delete it for you.

Comment: I was wondering how do you call `deleteCourse` and print results, could you add that part too?

Comment: In the code here  
if (index==0) {
        return this.next;
}
does nothing but return it.  If you are requesting to delete the 0th item it will just return the 0th item and it will still remain.

Comment: @JanOsch 4 java files are in there. 2 test files are scoring templates, so I cannot edit them. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dale But how can I disconnect with my previous node, only using recursive form...I wrote dropbox link of my codes, so if you have time, please check it and help me.

Comment: @gevorg I wrote dropbox link of my codes, so if you have time, please check it and help me.

Comment: @michip96 I think so... I don't know why only header makes problem...

Comment: I still don't see the 5th test in your code. Can you provide us with file name and line number where the 5th test starts ?

Comment: @JanOsch It is in 3rd case. I edited that part when I wrote this question.

Comment: Your approach is wrong.  Do not use indexes.  When using an index you are simply using a rotating array.  You should simply use the reference of the objects.  When removing a node you should simply say something like the following.   previousNode.nextNode = currentNode.next; currentNode = null;  In other words just go to the previous node and set it to the one after the current and erase the one you are on.  This avoids recursion and quite frankly while creating a linked list you shouldn't have to traverse the whole thing to remove a node.  I'm sure your professor will point this out if you do

Comment: See this image.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#/media/File:CPT-LinkedLists-deletingnode.svg  This is basically what I'm talking about.

Comment: I see a problem in your code: in `TestCourse:346`. Have you thought about a test case like this: `target = [1,3,1,1,5]` ? I belive it would result in elements: 1,2,3,4,5 being deleted

Comment: @JanOsch I am not allowed to change Test codes. Only Course and Schedule is editable.

Comment: @Dale Aha! I solved with your hint! Thank you very much.

Comment: Putting the answer down for the solution.  Please select it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an index you are simply using a rotating array. You should simply use the reference of the objects. When removing a node you should simply say something like the following. previousNode.nextNode = currentNode.next; currentNode = null; In other words just go to the previous node and set it to the one after the current and erase the one you are on. This avoids recursion and quite frankly while creating a linked list you shouldn't have to traverse the whole thing to remove a node. I'm sure your professor will point this out if you do.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#/media/File:CPT-LinkedLists-deletingnode.svg

Comment: Amazing. This hint gave me intuition. I can now deal with other linked lists. Thank you very much for your clear and useful help.